# ¿Cómo realizar consultas de actualización relacionales en mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, update, nosql

Estoy empezando con mongodb y me topo con el siguiente problema.
Tengo dos colecciones relacionadas entre si, una colección de usuarios, y otra colección de depósitos. La colección de usuarios se actualiza automáticamente cada 24 horas con los datos de los depósitos de cada usuario, cuando los depósitos llegan a un plazo de 15 días caducan (se eliminan) y pasan a saldo disponible. He tratado de realizar la función de varias formas, pero no hay manera que funcione. Les dejo el modelo de datos y una de las formas que estuve tratando:

Modelo de usuarios:

```
const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    balance: {
      type: Number,
      required: false,
    },
    earn: {
      type: Number,
      required: false,
    },
    dep1: {
      type: Number,
      required: false,
    },
    dep2: {
      type: Number,
      required: false,
    },
    dep3: {
      type: Number,
      required: false,
    },
    dep4: {
      type: Number,
      required: false,
    },
    dep5: {
      type: Number,
      required: false,
    },
    disponible: {
      type: Number,
      required: false,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
    versionKey: false,
  }
);
```

Modelo de depósitos:

```
const depositSchema = new Schema(
  {
    amount: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    plan: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    userId: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
    versionKey: false,
  }
);
```

Como se muestra el modelo depósitos tiene una relación por id con los usuarios. El campo plan en depósitos define el tipo de depósito, y el amount de este se agrega al dep del usuario. En dependencia del plan, cada dia se va actualizando el earn de los usuarios, pero al llegar al día 15 un depósito, este caduca (se elimina) el amount pasa a disponible y su valor se resta del dep del usuario. Como vemos necesitamos alguna forma de consultar ambas colecciones a la vez, trate de hacer un map pero me actualiza con el último valor solamente. Traté una forma un poco mas elaborada:

```
const userDeposit = await User.aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "deposits",
          localField: "_id",
          foreignField: "userId",
          as: "getInvest",
        },
      },
      {
        $unwind: "$getInvest",
      },
    ]);

    userInvest.map(async (userRes) => {
      const fechaCreado = Date.parse(
        JSON.stringify(userRes.getInvest.createdAt).split("T")[0].substring(1)
      );
      const fechaActual = Date.parse(
        JSON.stringify(new Date()).split("T")[0].substring(1)
      );
     if (fechaActual - fechaCreado >= 345600000) {
    var updatedUser = await User.updateOne({_id : userRes._id}, { $set : obj }, { upsert: true });
  }
 });
```

De esta forma logro unir las colecciones, pero no se de que forma hacer un update a todos los usuarios que retorna el userDeposit, como se observa intenté con el map, pero sucede lo mismo, toma el ultimo elemento y es lo que actualiza solamente. Como podría hacer para relacionar ambas colecciones de forma que pueda hacer un update a todos los usuarios. Los leo en los comentarios.

Comment: ¿Porqué el modelo de usuario tiene 5 claves iguales que sólo varían en nombre? No parece una buena forma de esquematizar el modelo. Eso en principio. Por otro lado, ¿cómo manejas el vencimiento de un depósito y porqué tienes la necesidad de *eliminarlo*? , nunca he visto algo parecido en finanzas, es decir, los registros financieros nunca se eliminan.

Comment: Por otro lado, ¿porqué guardar valores que pueden ser calculados (y que deberían ser calculados) al momento de una consulta? Es decir, en mi experiencia y en mi opinión, estás duplicando información y la misma puede incluso ser irrelevante o no exacta.

Comment: Hola Mauricio gracias por tu comentario. Si bien no das una solución, me ayudó a simplificar las colecciones y con ello las consultas. Sin embargo, en la colección de usuarios necesito el campo "disponible", y este se debe actualizar cuando los depósitos alcancen los 15 días. Para hacer esto uso un map, pero solo actualiza con el último elemento que recorre, como pidiera hacer que mientras valla recorrido valla actualizando. Saludos